# CUBA unique attribute on child class of joined inheritance not supported

Tags: cuba-platform

I have
- Contact class with joined inheritance
- Counterpart class extending Contact
- Customer extending Counterpart
- field 'code' in Customer I would like to be unique

Why is CUBA studio does not allow me to tick the 'unique' checkbox for the 'code' field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your entities implement the `SoftDelete` interface. It means that unique constraints must either include the `DELETE_TS` field or have a `where` condition with this field (depending on the database type).

In case of JOINED inheritance strategy the `DELETE_TS` field exists only in the root table, so the automatic creation of unique constraints is impossible for child entities.

You can create any constraints manually in the `30.create-db.sql` script, but keep in mind that if the unique index does not consider the soft deletion mark, users will not be able to create a new record with the same `CODE` as in a deleted record.